# How with delphi can I publish an iOS app to the account of someone else?

Tags: ios, delphi, iphone-developer-program, apple-developer

I build some iOS app for other people. With android it's quite simple, I gave the .aab to the guy and they add themself this .aab in the play store. However, I think, I can't do the same for iOS or I m mistaken?
Is there a way to compile the app on my computer and gave my client a binary so he can publish it under his account? I m under Delphi if it's matter.

What worry me a lot is that I need to compile a dozen of a white-labeled app every time I Update the main core app and I want to automatize the process. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 4):

An iOS app is compiled to an `.ipa` file, which can be deployed to a device or uploaded to the App Store.

However, iOS apps have many requirements beyond just deploying the binary.

Each customer will have to obtain a Developer Certificate that identifies them with the app(s) you develop on their behalf.  They will have to provide those certificates to you.

In order for each customer to then install/upload your app binary(s) on their own accord, they will have to register App IDs with Apple, and give you those IDs so you can configure it into your projects as needed.

Each customer will also have to provision those IDs according to how they will be installed (Ad-Hoc vs App Store), and give you the provisioning profiles so you can configure them into your projects as well.

This is all covered in Embarcadero's documentation:

[iOS Mobile Application Development](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/IOS_Mobile_Application_Development)

- [Acquiring an iOS Developer Certificate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Acquiring_an_iOS_Developer_Certificate)
- [Provisioning an iOS Application](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Provisioning_an_iOS_Application)

  - [Creating an App ID for Your Application](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Provisioning_an_iOS_Application#Creating_an_App_ID_for_Your_Application)
  - [Creating and Installing Your Provisioning Profiles](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Provisioning_an_iOS_Application#Creating_and_Installing_Your_Provisioning_Profiles)
  - [Configuring Your Provisioning Profiles on RAD Studio](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Provisioning_an_iOS_Application#Configuring_Your_Provisioning_Profiles_on_RAD_Studio)
- [Deploying Your Final iOS Application](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/IOS_Mobile_Application_Development#Deploying_Your_Final_iOS_Application)

  - [Deploying Your iOS Application for Ad-hoc Distribution](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Deploying_Your_iOS_Application_for_Ad_hoc_Distribution)
  - [Deploying Your iOS Application for Submission to the App Store](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Deploying_Your_iOS_Application_for_Submission_to_the_App_Store)

Comment: thanks Remy, but how I can automatize all this?  How he can gave me his provisioning profile? You mean I Can use in my own mac under my account his own provisioning profile?

Comment: "*how I can automatize all this?*" - you can't. "*How he can gave me his provisioning profile?*" - that is covered in the documentation I linked to. "*You mean I Can use in my own mac under my account his own provisioning profile?*" - you would have to, otherwise he couldn't publish your apps under his name/account, only under yours. For all intents and purposes, you would have to compile your app as if you *were* him

Comment: "You mean I Can use in my own mac under my account his own provisioning profile?" - you would have to, otherwise he couldn't publish your apps under his name/account, only under yours.  ==> wwoow If this work it's will be very great, I will make a try ! but I will be very surprising if just copying his profile and credential in my mac will work just like this